# Unity Container returning base type but wasn't before

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, web-config, unity-container, iis-express

I just got my unity config working, I started playing with web.config transformers and now it won't stop returning the base type.

I've stepped through the code to confirm the mapto value being picked up in my container is the correct type, everything shows it should be of the derived type; however the type returned is the base object.

Would unity cache the object somewhere? This is running in IIS Express for testing, could this be caching something?

It all started after I tried testing a register element transformation in the release.config (which would modify the MapTo to return the base type). Unfortunately once I tried that it won't go back, even after deleting the transform in my web.release.config file.

I'm not entirely sure that's the issue anyways since I can see the container object during runtime is showing the correct mapto object. Any thoughts or suggestions as to what's causing this?

My resolve code:

```
container.Resolve(Of SqlHelpers)(New ParameterOverride("connectionString", WebHelper.GetCurrentConnectionString))
```

My config code:

```
<container>
    <register name="SqlMap" type="SqlHelpers" mapTo="SqlHelpersForTesting">
      <lifetime type="external" />
      <constructor>
        <param name="connectionString">
        </param>
      </constructor>
    </register>
  </container>
```

My dubug transform code:

```
<unity>
<container>
  <add name="SqlMap" mapTo="SqlHelpersForTesting"
       xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
</container>
```

Deleted my release transform code but it was:

```
<unity>
<container>
  <add name="SqlMap" mapTo="SqlHelpers"
       xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
</container>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered after a lot of debugging that the mapping wasn't operating properly; this was because I added the name attribute to my `<register>` element. Documentation clearly shows name is an optional attribute but for whatever reason my configuration won't work with it. Soon as I remove it everything is in working order. If anyone can tell me what's going on with the name attribute that would be appreciated!

EDIT: My best guess would be the name attribute isn't optional in a register element for setting up an interception type map (because I added the constructor elements inside the register element?